# how to increase rosserial buffer size

Tags: navigation, odometry, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to publish an odometry message with rosserial:

nav_msgs::Odometry myOdom;

ros::Publisher odom_pub("odom", &myOdom);
....
odom_pub.publish(&myOdom);

and it compiles fine, but I get an error that the message exceeds the buffer:

[ERROR] [WallTime: 1376891179.350615] Message from device dropped: message larger than buffer.

I saw in the documentation:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosserial/Overview/Limitations

that the way to increase the buffer was by changing BUFFER_SIZE in the arduino library file ros.h
However, there is no such parameter in ros.h.  I did find in nodehandle.h the parameters INPUT_SIZE and OUTPUT_SIZE, so I tried changing those from 512 to 1024, but the initial INFO message that comes up still says that the max buffer size is 512.

I searched for where the error message is being sent from and found it also in nodehandle.h and changed it to include in the error note the size of the message I am trying to send.  It's possible the odom message is > 512 bytes, but if I can find out how many bytes are trying to be sent, then, once I find BUFFER_SIZE, I will know what it needs to be set to.

That change did not show up in the error, so now I realize that when I am recompiling the arduino code, the changes I made to nodehandle.h are not being incorporated.  The file is located in the correct place (...sketchbook/libraries/ros_lib/ros) and I closed and reopened the arduino IDE, so it should pick up the change.

Thanks for the help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/73627/how-to-increase-rosserial-buffer-size/) by [dan](https://answers.ros.org/users/144/dan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 875 on 2013-08-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So the proper place to change this is in rosserial_arduino/src/ros.h. The numbers supplied there will overwrite the defaults in node_handle.h. I believe we split the template parameter BUFFER_SIZE into INPUT/OUTPUT_SIZE a while ago and probably forgot to update the docs -- be sure to change the template parameters for the chip you are actually using (note the various #ifdefs for different size AVR chips). Also, if increasing the buffer size, you should probably reduce the number of pubs/subs to keep down overall memory usage.

As for the chagnes not showing up -- perhaps it's not rebuilding due to the header file change? The arduino buildsystem is pretty funky, if you turn on verbose compile/upload under the Preferences menu, you should be able to see where it is putting the built files (typically somewhere under /tmp for linux machines) -- try deleting that folder to force a full rebuild?

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-08-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dan](https://answers.ros.org/users/144/dan/) on 2013-08-19**:
this comment section has character limits so that I had to ask my followup in the form of the "answer" below.
Your suggestion to do a verbose build was great-- I had renamed a backup version of ros_lib to ros_lib_old and for some reason it was using the files there.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What board are you using?  512 is the default for the ATmega2650  and ATmega1280.  If you want to increase it for these boards, define it in the ros.h according to which board you are using.

---

Originally posted by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) with karma: 2549 on 2013-08-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dan](https://answers.ros.org/users/144/dan/) on 2013-08-20**:
I am using an ATmega2560.  Sorry, but how do I define it for that board in ros.h?
Perhaps I am being a bit dense here. Is this correct to get 10 pubs, 10 subs, 1024 bytes for pubs, 512 for subs?
#elif defined(**AVR_ATmega2560**)
typedef NodeHandle_<ArduinoHardware,10,10,1024,512> NodeHandle;

**Comment by [dan](https://answers.ros.org/users/144/dan/) on 2013-08-20**:
That worked, but note that the order of the buffers seems pubs then subs.  It now accepts the messages, with this error (opened a new question)
raise genpy.DeserializationError(e) #most likely buffer underfill
genpy.message.DeserializationError: unpack requires a string argument of length 288

**Comment by [irsyadtc](https://answers.ros.org/users/38009/irsyadtc/) on 2019-07-24**:
If I'm using OpenCR board, how do I set the defined name in ros.h?

here's the link to the board info
http://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/parts/controller/opencr10/

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found this thread a bit hard to follow, but managed to figure out how to fix the problem. This is assuming you have the same error when using nav_msgs/odometry.

Wherever your Arduino libraries are located, there should be a folder for your ROS libraries. When you first installed ROS, it was named 'ros_lib', In this folder, you'll find 'ros.h', as well as 'node_handle.h' in a folder called 'ros'.

> [Arduino Libraries] ---> ros_lib ---> **ros.h**
>
> [Arduino Libraries] ---> ros_lib ---> ros ---> **node_handle.h**

The relevant portion of the **ros.h** file looks like:

```
#ifndef _ROS_H_
#define _ROS_H_

#include "ros/node_handle.h"
#include "ArduinoHardware.h"

namespace ros
{
#if defined(__AVR_ATmega8__) || defined(__AVR_ATmega168__)
  /* downsize our buffers */
  typedef NodeHandle_<ArduinoHardware, 6, 6, 150, 150> NodeHandle;

#elif defined(__AVR_ATmega328P__)

  typedef NodeHandle_<ArduinoHardware, 25, 25, 280, 280> NodeHandle;

#else

  typedef NodeHandle_<ArduinoHardware> NodeHandle;

#endif   
}

#endif
```

Assuming you're using the Atmega2560, you can paste this between the #elif and #else. The numbers define in order [MAX_SUBSCRIBERS, MAX_PUBLISHERS, INPUT_SIZE, OUTPUT_SIZE].

```
#elif defined(__AVR_ATmega2560__)

  typedef NodeHandle_<ArduinoHardware, 15, 15, 512, 1024> NodeHandle;
```

I believe this method was the proper place to change the buffer sizes, as mentioned by fergs.

An alternative solution is to alter **node_handle.h** instead. It seems like this is what the OP dan ended up doing.

The relevant portion of the **node_handle.h** file looks like:

```
namespace ros {

  using rosserial_msgs::TopicInfo;

  /* Node Handle */
  template<class Hardware,
           int MAX_SUBSCRIBERS=25,
           int MAX_PUBLISHERS=25,
           int INPUT_SIZE=512,
           int OUTPUT_SIZE=512>
  class NodeHandle_ : public NodeHandleBase_
  {
```

Here, you can change the OUTPUT_SIZE from 512 to 1024. I personally had to decrease MAX_SUBSCRIBERS and MAX_PUBLISHERS and publishers from 25 to 15, otherwise my rosserial node wouldn't work.

After doing this, save the file you editted and recompile/upload your Arduino code, and it should eliminate the buffer size error from using nav_msgs/odometry.

---

Originally posted by [bwlim](https://answers.ros.org/users/30106/bwlim/) with karma: 51 on 2017-04-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mattMGN](https://answers.ros.org/users/29874/mattmgn/) on 2018-02-25**:
Really clear, thank you for that explanation!